# Delete the last line of a StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I know that when we use a StreamWriter this is, by definition, to write in it but the fact is that at some point I can have the obligation to delete the last line of my streamwriter...

I found the following code (on SO) that works well :

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pluginQmlFileName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(pluginQmlFileName, lines.Take(lines.Length - 1).ToArray());
```

but the thing is that I can't use it in my :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pluginQmlFileName, true))
{
    [...]
}
```

section.

Is there a way to delete the last line in the `using {}` section or do I have to keep my actual code ?

Comment: How you write? If you got some kind of loop, just don't write if you're in the last iteration.

Comment: Yep, there is a loop but the fact is that when Im writing the last line, I have NO IDEA if I will delete it later :/ It will be too long to explain but I can only check in the next looping that I have to delete it... :(

Comment: So why not use `List<string>` to store the lines you want to write then only after the "next looping" use `File.WriteAllLines` to write the lines? Removing last line from List is trivial. :)

Comment: Well, I didnt exaplin myself correctly :( Im writing in a loop but the loop is in a function and Im sometimes deleting the last line when I enter the function again ! (thats why Im opening the StreamWriter with the "true" argument) and the fact is that I can only do my test when the StreamWriter is already opened :/

Comment: Well... here's a **terrible** idea: keep the last line, and instead of writing it, return it (using `out` or whatever) to the caller. The caller can keep passing it back to your function, and your function can decide if it should write it or not. But honestly, it sounds like your mixing business logic ("Should I write?") into regular code ("How do I write?"). Try separating those things. Maybe looping inside the writing function is not the best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that a StreamWriter allows you to do this, but perhaps you could make your own stream wrapper which implements this behavior? That is, it would keep the last line in memory and only write it out when another line comes in.

Comment: Yup, that's how I would do it. But only if I **had** to write into a SteamWriter. It seems simpler not to do the write in the first place, no?

Comment: thats a "heavy" solution in my code... :( And about not writing it, see my comment on my question (@scraimer)

Comment: Well, yes, that is a bit heavy. Why didn't you like the idea about storing all the lines in a List and then writing them all out once you're done with the loopings?

Answer (score 4):

You could just remove the last line after reading in them all:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(pluginQmlFileName);

// will need changing to remove from the array if using ReadAllLines instead of ReadLines
lines = lines.RemoveAt(lines.Count - 1);
```

Comment: Doesnt really help with my StreamWriter problem but thats a nice tip!

Comment: It depends what you're doing in between the read and write. If you're reading then writing immediately after and know that you want to remove the last line that it would be worth doing that. Although if not and you end up storing the lines then you could remove the last line just before writing to the file via the StreamWriter. Otherwise it might be worth looking at the TextWriter.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work with me as well :

//you must attemp to close all open streams of that file if any
//if you are using it inside `using (StreamWriter sw = .... ) {....}`
//attempt => `sw.close();`
//then

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.SetLength(fs.Length - 1);
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can not remove any data from a stream opened by a StreamWriter. StreamWriter is designed to write in a file, so you can not remove anything explicitly.

So have to use an other class to read file content and then since [StreamWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) inherited from [TextWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywxh2328.aspx) you should be able using [WriteLine(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) method but this doesn't not make sense since you already have a pretty nice working code.

```
// read all lines
// ...
var allExceptLast = lines.Take(lines.Length - 1);
foreach(var line in allExceptLast)
{
   writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: True, but even with TextWriter there's no "RemoveLine" method. Once the text is written, it can't be undone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your above code, `lines` is effectively an array of strings, as `ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings.

Instead of thinking in terms of "removing the last line", I'd rather think of "not writing the last line", so what you could do:

```
string[] lines = ...; // Note that I'm using an array here!

using (...)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < lines.Length-1 || !condition)
            sw.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

This writes all lines up to the second last line. The last line is only written if the condition is false.

Comment: would be extremely hard to use it with my code :( the comment on my question should explain why !

Answer (score 0):

That's how I'd solve the problem:

```
StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);
int countLines = 0;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    countLines++;
    if (countLines == lines.Count)
    {
        //Write doesn't insert "/r/n" on the end of line
        myFile.Write(line.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        //WriteLine insert "/r/n" on the end of a line
        myFile.WriteLine(line.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("idk"))
{
                string line;
                bool first = true;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!first)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine();
                    }
                    sw.Write(line);
                    first = false;
                }
```

}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?